# Trouble with CSS transitions from one image to another

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

so I have a slideshow of images on my site right now, and I am trying to add a transition when the image changes, but I'm having no success. I've attached the html(shortened), javascript, and CSS code for the slideshow (the image I'm trying to affect with the transition is id="slideshowImg"), and if anyone sees what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

**HTML CODE**
(essentially a table, with the top row the image that changes, and the bottom row, which contains multiple images for the different article, which I'm not trying to add transition to)

```
<body onload="imageChange()">
<div id="imageDiv">
<table id="mediaMenu">
    <tr>
        <td id="imageRow" colspan="3" >
            <img id="slideshowImg"  src="images/tebow.jpg" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></img>
        </td>
        <td id="detailPar" colspan="2">
            <a id="introText">Tim Tebow talks about Aaron Hernandez</a>
            <p id="detailsPar">tebowtebowtebow</p>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="subMenu">
            <a href="#" onclick="doEverything(0)">
            <table> 
                <tr> <td class="subTitle"> Tebow Talks </td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="images/tebow.jpg" alt="Tim Tebow"></img></td></tr> 
            </table>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu">
            <a href="#" onclick="doEverything(1)">
            <table>
                <tr> <td class="subTitle">Nash attack </td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="images/nash.jpg" alt="Steve Nash"></img></td></tr>
            </table>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu">
            <a href="#" onclick="doEverything(2)">
            <table>
                <tr> <td class="subTitle">Kobe Who? </td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="images/kobe.jpg" alt="Kobe Bryant"></img></td></tr>
            </table>
            </a>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>                 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE***

```
slideshowImages = new Array(5);
slideshowImages[0] = new Image();
slideshowImages[0].src = 'images/tebow.jpg';
//rest of image array in same way

function slideShow(source)
{
document.getElementById('slideshowImg').src = slideshowImages[source].src;
clearInterval(newPic);
index=source;
imageChange();
}
function slideshowForward() 
{
index++;    
if(index >= 5) 
{
    index=0;
}
// set the image name to the slide show image
document.getElementById('slideshowImg').src = slideshowImages[index].src;
document.getElementById('introText').innerHTML = introText[index];
document.getElementById('detailsPar').innerHTML = introDetails[index];

}
function imageChange() {
newPic=setInterval(function(){slideshowForward() },5000);
}
function doEverything(textPar) {
 getText(textPar); //code not included, but this doesn't affect the image
 slideShow(textPar);
}
</script>
```

**CSS for image I'm trying to affect**

```
#slideshowImg {
width:100%;
height:300px;
margin:0px;
border-spacing:20px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: My opinion is that you have to choose between `tables` and `animations` because from my experience they are not the best of friends.

Comment: haha thats unfortunate. Strangely enough, when I changed the CSS to slideshowImg:hover{...}, both transitions and transformations worked, but I just couldn't get them to work by themselves when the image changes...

Comment: ***Tables*** .. **tables** .. *tables*....